# "No such module 'Firebase'" // framework not found FirebaseUI

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, cocoapods

I previously had Firebase connected to my app with the below pods (excluding pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks) and it was working just fine. I was using the line 'import Firebase' at the top of each view controller to import the relevant frameworks.

However, today I went to add pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks' and when I went to run pod install, it got stuck 'analyzing dependencies'. I read through other forums on stackoverflow to fix this issue. I ended up removing cocoapods from my project and reinstalling them. I now have reinstalled the pods, but when I open Xcode I get the message 'No such module 'Firebase'. It essentially wants me to import specific Firebase modules [import FirebaseDatabase, import FirebaseAnalytics, etc.] instead of just [import Firebase]. After updating the import on all of my view controllers, there is 1 issue remaining -> 'Framework not found FirebaseUI'.

**Questions**

- Is going from 'import Firebase' to 'import FirebaseDatabase, etc.' recommended or is this a step backwards?
- How can I resolve 'Framework not found FirebaseUI'? I have the pod installed already.

**Other info that may help**

- When running pod install, I get a warning notification: [!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs
- When trying to build project, I also get: *ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/[myNameHere]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[AppName]-dtipemvgjzrgzvephbatansalrwu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Firebase'*
- As well as: *ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/[myNameHere]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[AppName]-dtipemvgjzrgzvephbatansalrwu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseUI'*

**My podfile**

- pod 'FirebaseUI'
- pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
- pod 'Firebase/Core'
- pod 'Firebase/Database'
- pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
- pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
- pod 'Firebase/Storage'
- pod 'Firebase/Auth'
- pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
- pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'
- pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks' (new)

Comment: Try cleaning the project using **cmd + shift + k** or restarting the project

Comment: You might have a corrupt Xcode module cache. Try `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rereading the Firebase documentation, it turns out "You no longer need to add the iOS pod Firebase/Core. This SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics."

I ended up removing Core and the UI Cocoapods (using my own UI buttons instead) and the project now builds. I assume there may be an error installing the UI Framework with the FirebaseUI Cocoapod - idk.

Pods removed:
 - pod 'Firebase/Core'
 - pod 'FirebaseUI'
 - pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
 - pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
 - pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'